# Coding user availability for activity as boolean (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list of events. Users can mark their availability whereby an entry will be created in the Availability table against their user ID, event ID and their availability as a boolean.

I have two links (not form buttons) on the event show view, one for available (true) and one for unavailable (false) but am stuck with the backend. Do I need three actions?

1. Store new record for availability as true
2. Store new record for availability as false
3. Update (patch) existing record for true or false

How would you do it as best practice? I feel like there must be an easier/cleaner way of doing it than that.

I'm also stuck with the route as I'm used to actioning the database based on forms. I assume it will be the following as an example:

`Route::get('/events/{event}/unavailable','EventAvailabilityController@unavailable');`

How would you get the event ID to the model?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a Patch route so I can set it true or false (1 endpoint).

```
Route::patch('/events/{event}/status','EventAvailabilityController@changeStatus');
```

If you want to get the Id of the model you can do this:

```
public function changeStatus(Request $request, EventModel $eventModel) {
    $request->validate([
        'status' => 'boolean|required'
    ]);

    $event->status = $request->status;
    $event->save();

    return response()->json(['event' => $event]);
}
```

Note: Replace event `EventModel` with your model and `changeStatus` with your function.